How to build HTML files with no dependency in using grunt?
I have a project where there are html files that include dependencies (css links, javascript links, image links, font links, favicon.ico).
Using Grunt, I want to compile each html file so that I have dependency-free html files: I want all the dependencies to be included (minified) in the html files.
For example, if I have two html files :

file1.html includes file1.js, file2.js, file1.css, file2.css.
file2.html includes file2.js, file3.js, file2.css, file3.css.

file1.html must include the content of file1.js and file2.js but not the content of file3.js.
file2.html must include the content of file2.js and file3.js but not the content of file1.js.
How can I do this? I've found tutorials that explain how to concatenate and minify css/js files but I can't find how to integrate them into HTML files with images and fonts.
I want to do this because I want to integrate these web pages into a small web server that needs to reduce the number of HTTPS sockets per user as much as possible (the size of the files on the server is secondary).
